# Full Join working like an inner join - it has multiple join conditions (no where clause included)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hive

I'm trying to do a full join on two tables that looks like this below. What I'm expecting with my full join is any combinations of the data not in table1 are pulled in from table2 but when I run this query some rows from table2 are eliminated and it's behaving like an inner join.

Some specifics about this are that category1, category2 and category3 are essentially when I'm missing metadata about a group and are thus just manually hardcoded as "Unknown".

I did some digging and the rows from table2 that are missing are these rows that say "Unknown", I don't know what relevance that has though since the actual values for category1 and category2 are also just text strings so my thinking is it should treat "Unknown" as any other text string and with the full join just introduce rows for that from table2.

All the solutions I've searched for so far with a full join behaving like an inner join are because of where clauses forcing them to behave like an inner join. Any pointers here would be helpful!

Finally, I'm using Hive on Spark for my querying if that helps.

```
SELECT a.date AS date,
       a.group AS group,
       a.category1,
       a.category2,
       a.category3,
       COALESCE(a.metric1,0) AS signups,
       COALESCE(b.metric2,0) AS gnc 
FROM table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 b 
       ON a.date = b.date
      AND a.group= b.group
      AND LOWER(a.category1) = LOWER(b.category1)
      AND LOWER(a.category2) = LOWER(b.category2)
      AND LOWER(a.category3) = LOWER(b.category3)
```

This is roughly what the tables look like

```
Table 1 

Date         Group Category1 Category2 Category3 Metric1
1/1/2001       B      ABC        DEF     GHI       1  
......
12/11/2022     A      XYZ        DEF     GHI       2

Table 2

Date         Group Category1 Category2 Category3 Metric2

1/1/2001       B      ABC        DEF     GHI       5  
......
12/11/2022     A    Unknown    Unknown  Unknown    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Still unsure what was happening with the join but essentially the full join was functioning as an inner join, my best guess is due to the data set up, the join condition was behaving like a de-factor where clause and filtering out rows from the right table and since I didn't have an actual where clause I didn't have the option of moving them anywhere.

I looked for alternatives to the full join and instead did a union of my two tables and then a group by of the now unioned tables. [Turns out](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/04/19/full-outer-joins/) you almost never need to a full join, that's a good resource to read up on.

Note : Both table 1 and 2 in my case were cleaned up and had null's cleaned up and were pre-aggregated.

```
With agg AS (

SELECT group,
       category1,
       category2,
       category3,
       metric1,
       0 AS metric2
  FROM table1

UNION 

SELECT group,
       category1,
       category2,
       category3,
       0 AS metric1,
       metric2
  FROM table2 ) 

SELECT group,
       category1,
       category2,
       category3,
       SUM(metric1) AS metric1,
       SUM(metric2) AS metric2
  FROM table2
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```